# How to save a file which is read directly from the URL with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a portfolio project that involves analysing weather data. To obtain the weather data I have written the below script to download the yearly weather data automatically and save it into a .csv file.

However, my script is not working properly as it is not able to output the.csv file read from the URL. While debugging the code, I noticed that the .csv file is read and loaded into the memory.

```py
def download_data(station_id, start_year, end_year = 2022):
    
    template_url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/{}/{}"
    Path("./downloaded_data").mkdir(parents= True, exist_ok= True)
    
    for year in range(start_year, end_year+1):
    
        file_url = template_url.format(str(year), str(station_id)+".csv")
        data_df = pd.read_csv(file_url)
        data_df.to_csv("./downloaded_data/{}.csv".format(str(year), mode='w+'), index= False, encoding= 'utf-8')
        print("downloaded: {}".format(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

After running your code with some test data I was able to achieve what you wanted.

If you could give any more context to your issue that would be great; for example, pandas or python version etc.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import sys

print(f'Py version: {sys.version}')
# Py version: 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
print(f'Pd version: {pd.__version__}')
# Pd version: 1.4.2


def download_data(station_id, start_year, end_year=2022):
    template_url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/{}/{}"
    Path("./downloaded_data").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        file_url = template_url.format(str(year), str(station_id) + ".csv")
        data_df = pd.read_csv(file_url)
        data_df.to_csv("./downloaded_data/{}.csv".format(f'{station_id}_{str(year)}', mode='w+'), index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        print("downloaded: {}".format(f'{station_id}_{str(year)}'))


test_data = {
    'station_id': ['03005099999', '01088799999', '02615099999'],
    'start_year': 2020,
}

for i in test_data['station_id']:
    download_data(i, test_data['start_year'])
```

As mentioned, I was able to download the csv files (I made a minor modification to your code with regard to output filenames, just for clarity it now has a prefix which is the station id).

[Image of the modified file name structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRSz.png)